# Boost Python and C++ header files

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I want to provide `python` interface to my `C++ shared library`, I am planning to use `Boost::python` for the same, my `C++` code based is huge and divided across `headers` and `implementation` files. But all the `python::boost` examples talks about adding `python::boost` constructs in `cpp` files and how to deal this for header files. and Can I have same code based so that I can build both `C++` shared library and `python modules`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a link to a guide on how to use Boost.Python: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html

Example using header / implementation structure:

```
//hpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg);
    std::string greet();
    std::string msg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
    ;
}

//cpp

void World::set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
std::string greet() { return this->msg; }
```

Comment: ok, so no need to worry about implementation file, only need to expose the methods in Header file right !!!

Comment: @Avinash: Yes, see the link I provided for more details. Some types can be automatically exposed (e.g. int, std::string), some have to be exposed by you. Custom types (e.g. MyCustomContainer) always need to be exposed by you.

Comment: it's World::greet()